# Facebook app, post status after allowing access

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

Ok so I have setup a Login via Facebook on my website, after they click it, it will then authenticate with Facebook and come up with this:

http://prntscr.com/38pfth

Once they click play now it will then successfully login via Facebook and redirect them to home page.

But after they click Play Now I would like it so that the user that authenticated it will then post a status saying something like "I just logged into ..... via Facebook"

How can I do this?
thanks

Comment: Can you show your login/auth code by editing the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that when the user connected / logged in to your app/game you have asked for the correct permissions it should be pretty easy. Below is some code I wrote for a project of mine. The user would have had to specifically allowed the app to publish to the stream on their behalf.

Pay special attention to the :

```
{scope: 'publish_stream'}
```

This will ask the user during the connection phase if it's ok for your game/app to publish to the stream on the users behalf.

```
// Click Handler for the login. 
$(document).delegate('#fb-connect', 'click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    FB.login(function(response) {

    // Check the status
    // console.log(response.status);

    if (response.status === 'connected') {

       // Run the function we created below to publish to the users stream.  
       publish('I just logged in via Facebook. '); // Your Message 

    } else if (response.status === 'unknown' || response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // Something else if they chose not to connect
    } else {

    }

    }, {scope: 'publish_stream'});

});
```

This is a simple function that you can pass a string to (your message) and will post to the currently connected users stream.

```
function publish(messagebody) {

var body = messagebody; // This is the passed in string aka message you want to post. 


params = {
    message: body, // Your message body
    link: 'http://www.yoursite.com' // if you want to share a link. 
}

FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    //alert('Error occured');
    console.log(response.error);
  } else {
    // Successful post to facebook.
    // alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);

  }
});
}
```

Hope this helps you!

**EDIT: Adding FULL HTML Example page.**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your Page</title>
    <!-- Load the Facebook SDK for your APP -->
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
          appId   : 'YOURAPPID', // Test App ID for localhost
          channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
          status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
          xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
        });

        // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
      };

      // Load the SDK asynchronously
      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
</head>
<body>


<!-- Markup for Connect Button -->
<a id="fb-connect">
    <img src="URLTOANIMAGEYOULIKEFORTHEBUTTON">
</a>

<!--  Reference to Jquery -->
<script src="PATHTOJQUERY"></script>

<!-- Some Additional Script to handle the functions / Could also be another JS file you include.  -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Bind the Click of the Button fb-connect
    $(document).delegate('#fb-connect', 'click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        FB.login(function(response) {

        // Check the status
        // console.log(response.status);

        if (response.status === 'connected') {

           // Run the function we created below to publish to the users stream.  
           publish('I just logged in via Facebook. '); // Your Message 

        } else if (response.status === 'unknown' || response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // Something else if they chose not to connect
        } else {

        }

        }, {scope: 'publish_stream'});

    });
});


function publish(messagebody) {

    var body = messagebody; // This is the passed in string aka message you want to post. 


    params = {
        message: body, // Your message body
        link: 'http://www.yoursite.com' // if you want to share a link. 
    }

    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        //alert('Error occured');
        console.log(response.error);
      } else {
        // Successful post to facebook.
        // alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);

      }
    });
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank so much for the reply, I'm new to PHP and this facebook login stuff, where would I add that? Heres my files http://pastebin.com/u/Ronnieem8
thanks again

Comment: This code is javascript. So you would need to include it in the page you plan on having the connect button. This script also uses jQuery, so you'll have to load that before you execute this code. Best to load jQuery before the close </body> tag. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Hi again, thanks a lot, you're very helpful!
This is the page the login via facebook button is on: http://pastebin.com/kTmwsrvK
where would i put the code and how do I load Jquery before the code?
thanks once again, very new to this

Comment: I can't access pastebin at work. Sorry. But as long as you have a FB app ID, jQuery on the page and this code with an html link with the ID of  #fb-connect in your page it will work.

Comment: UPDATE :  I added some more code above. this should help you understand the proper setup to get this working. I also noticed you removed this as the accepted answer. :( why?

Comment: Sorry, must of removed it by accident, you're very helpful, really appreciate you helping me at work :)
When you get home do you think you can help me a bit more, I can't seem to do it as I'm using a script given to me for my site as it's a game site, I don't know where to put the code you given. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hey @xCNPx think you could help me out now if you're not busy, I'm having trouble adding the code to my current code